# Prove $P(\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i) \ge \sum_{i=1}^nP(A_i)-\sum_{1\le i \lt j \le n}P(A_i \cap A_j)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $A_1, A_2,...A_n$ be events. Prove $$P(\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i) \ge \sum_{i=1}^nP(A_i)-\sum_{1\le i \lt j \le n}P(A_i \cap A_j)$$

I think this statement is intuitively obvious but I don''t know how to prove it.
I already tried to use induction and here is my work:

Base case: $n=2$ $$P(A_1 \cup A_2)=P(A_1)+P(A_2)-P(A_1 \cap A_2)$$
Assume this is true for $n$.
I want to show $$P(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n+1}A_i) \ge \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}P(A_i)-\sum_{1\le i \lt j \le {n+1}}P(A_i \cap A_j)$$ and I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 4):

This can be expressed as an inequality $E(Y)\ge0$ for a certain random variable $Y$.

Let $X_i$ be the indicator function of the set $A_i$. Then
$$Y=\max(X_1,\ldots,X_n)-\sum_{i=1}^n X_i+\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}X_iX_j.$$
All one has to do is to prove that $Y\ge0$. If $\omega$ is a point
in the sample space in exactly $k\ge1$ of the $A_i$ then
$$Y(\omega)=1-k+\frac{k(k-1)}2=\frac{(k-1)(k-2)}{2}\ge0$$
etc.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
P(A_{n+1} \cup (\cup^n A_i)) 
&= P(A_{n+1}) + P(\cup^n A_i) - P(A_{n+1} \cap (\cup^n A_i))\\
&\geq P(A_{n+1}) + \sum^n P(A_i) - \sum_{i<j}^{n} P(A_i \cap A_j) - P(\cup^n(A_i \cap A_{n+1}))\\
&\geq \sum^{n+1} P(A_i) - \sum_{i<j}^{n+1} P(A_i \cap A_j)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

First equality is the base case, first inequality is the induction.

For the last inequality you need,
\begin{equation}
\sum_i^n P(A_i \cap A_{n+1}) \geq P(\cup^n (A_i \cap A_{n+1}))
\end{equation}
but this is : $\left[\sum P(B_i) \geq P(\cup B_i)\right]$.